# Transform Spring MVC web application into a console application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I've got a `Maven-based` `Spring MVC` `webapp`, which structure looks like this:

[image: project schema]

After build it creates a `.war` and deploys it to an `application server`. `HomeController` has request mapping to some url patterns and return `.jsp` according to given request.

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.HEAD})
    public String homeGET(Model model) {
        // perform some actions
        return homeView;
    }
```

I'd need to find the smoothest way, how to transform this, into a `console` `.jar` application. To make it easier, let's say, I've got just one view and I don't need to handle different url request patterns.

Comment: embed a webserver in your program will do this, tomcat or jetty will do this. otherwise integration spring boot, it does everything for you

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/)

Answer (score 1):

The eaisest way to go is to port the project and base it on spring-boot, which ofters packaging as a war or an executable jar as a simple config option. Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Comment: This seems to be a nice tool, but it will just pack the whole stuff into a jar. 1) It won't turn it into a console app 2) It won't enbetter the performance which was the main goal - to get rid of the application server